# Required Validation not working on mat-select with [(NgModel)]

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select

I have a Material Stepper, in the second Step I have 4 mat-select. All the selects are required, but the problem is that with ngModel I'm binding the property inicialized in my models (example Id=0) so the select is always "valid" even if the user doesn't touch the select and if so he can move on to the next Step.
I have simplify the code so it's easier to understand:

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
              <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
                <ng-template matStepLabel>Tipo de Proyecto</ng-template>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-label>Disciplina</mat-label>
                  <mat-select name="discipline" formControlName="discipline" [(ngModel)]="project.disciplineId" required>
                    <mat-option>---</mat-option>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let disciplin of disciplines" [value]="disciplin.id">
                      {{ disciplin.name }}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
                <div>
                  <button class="btn-atras" mat-button matStepperPrevious>Atras</button>
                  <button mat-button matStepperNext>Siguiente</button>
                </div>
              </form>
</mat-step>
```

Model:

```
export class ProjectRequest {
    name: string;
    objective: string;
    description: string;
    startDate: Date;
    estimatedEndDate: Date;
    locationId: number;
    disciplineId: number;
    categoryId: number

    constructor() {
        this.name = "",
        this.objective = "",
        this.description = "",
        this.startDate = new Date(),
        this.estimatedEndDate = new Date(),
        this.locationId = 0,
        this.disciplineId = 0,
        this.categoryId = 0
    }
}
```

component.ts:

```
project = new ProjectRequest;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      discipline: [null, Validators.required]
    });
}
```

So I've been looking everywhere for an answer and I don't know how to fix it. Thank you!

Edit: I fixed it just setting null at all the initial values for my selects in their respective model. Anyway, idk if this is the right way.

Comment: in stackblitz you will have the dependencies section on the left side... you will get one text field to enter the package name to add

Answer (score 0):

You figured out the correct answer here, mat-select required validator requires that the value of the bound property must be null.  Setting the values to null is fine, but sometimes I run into issues when the model has a non-nullable integer value and defaults to 0.  (Like from an API).

In cases like this you would want to create a custom validator.  Here is one that only considers a positive number the only valid value.

```
export function selectRequiredValidator(ctrl: AbstractControl): ValidatorFn 
{
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
       return (control.value && control.value > 0) ? null : { required: { value: control.value } };
    };
}
```

Set to your control:

```
this.form.controls['discipline'].setValidators([selectRequiredValidator, Validators.required]);
```